# What is basic cost in linear programming?

Tags: notation, linear-programming

Just started learning LP, can someone please explain what is c bar? What's the meaning of it? (the fancy B is the basis, the fancy N represents other indices)[image: definition]

Comment: It looks like $\mathbf{\bar c}$ is the total cost.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\bar{c}\in\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ represents the vector of objective function coefficients.

Comment: thanks- figured out myself